# Is the multiplicative order of $n$ modulo a Cullen prime always a power of two?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For natural $n$, let $C_n = n\cdot 2^n+1$. If $n$ is such that $C_n$ is a prime (a so-called [Cullen prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cullen_number)), is it true that the multiplicative order of $n$ modulo prime $C_n$ is a power of two?

Checking the first many [known cases](https://oeis.org/A005849) seems to support the idea. But what is the explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mod $C_n$ if $C_n$ is prime (so that $n \geq 1$),

$n^{2^n} \equiv (-1)^{2^n}(2^{-n})^{2^n} \equiv 2^{1-C_n} \equiv 1$ by Fermat’s Little Theorem.